# How to check if data is missing after two or more repeating values in pandas and replace missing value with previous value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to fill missing values with previous value but only if the previous value is repeating?
**Sample DF:**

```
Index Columns
0    1978.0
1    1918.0
2    1918.0
3    1918.0
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7    1853.0
8    1831.0
9       NaN
```

for the above dataframe replace NaN at index 4,5,6 with 1918.0 and leave NaN at index 8 as NaN.

**Desired Output 1:**

```
Index Columns
0    1978.0
1    1918.0
2    1918.0
3    1918.0
4    1918.0
5    1918.0
6    1918.0
7    1853.0
8    1831.0
9       NaN
```

And also it would be great if I could get number of instances it occurred like that out of all NaN value.
ie; Sample DF has 4 NaN values in which 3 NaN values occured like that.

**Desired Output 2:**

```
Column_Name  : Columns
Total_NaN_count : 4
NaN_values_with_previous_elements_repeating : 3
```

Please let me know if there is any way to get this.

Thanks

Comment: @jeremycg thanks for the edit, this is my first time posting :)

Answer (score 4):

You can select the dataframe with condition and ffill on that

```
cond = df['Columns'].shift(1) == df['Columns'].shift(2)
df.loc[cond] = df.loc[cond].ffill()

    Columns
0   1978.0
1   1918.0
2   1918.0
3   1918.0
4   1918.0
6   1853.0
7   1831.0
8   NaN
```

Update: This handles the new test case

```
cond = (df.Columns.shift(1) == df.Columns.shift(2)) | (df.Columns.shift(-2).notnull())
df.loc[:] = df.fillna(df.loc[cond].ffill())
```

You get

```
    Columns
0   1978.0
1   1918.0
2   1918.0
3   1918.0
4   1918.0
5   1918.0
6   1918.0
7   1853.0
8   1831.0
9   NaN
```

Comment: something similar: `x.Columns[(x.Columns.shift(1) == x.Columns.shift(2)) & np.isnan(x.Columns)] = x.Columns.shift(1)`

Comment: @Vaishali and jeremycg, thank you for the answers but I would like to fill all the next NaN values and not just one NaN value. I have modified the sample data frame and output data frame to make it clear (Sorry should have asked clearly before).

Comment: @Vaishali but it works if there are only 3 NaN values? I would like it to work irrespective of number of NaN values between. I tried for a df with more than 3 NaN values in between and its missing few NaN values.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a NumPy way working on the underlying array data for performance and convenience -

```
# Extract array data which being a view lets us modify the original
# dataframe later on just by modifying it
a = df.Columns.values

# Indices of NaN positions that also have repeating values preceding to them
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[False,False,a[1:-1] == a[:-2]] & np.isnan(a))

# Finally assign previous values for all those places
a[idx] = a[idx-1]
```

Comment: I think all pandas questions should have a numpy tag... just to see some numpy magic from you!

Comment: @Divakar, thank you for the answer but I would like to fill all the next NaN values and not just one NaN value. I have modified the sample data frame and output data frame to make it clear (Sorry should have asked clearly before).